# Do not see compile time error in eclipse maven project

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-plugin, m2eclipse

I have created maven project in eclipse but I don't see any compile time error (red color indication) in eclipse but when i run maven clean install i can see compilation error
Am i missing any maven plugin, please help

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: I am able to successfully build maven program from command prompt, but when i am trying to build it from eclipse maven it is giving error.

Comment: Please update your post with the stack trace of your error.